# How to solve: `<module:Hashie>': superclass mismatch for class Rash (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Suddenly I cannot run the server. It throws following output:

### Heading ##/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rash-0.2.0/lib/rash.rb:5:in `': superclass mismatch for class Rash (TypeError)

```
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rash-0.2.0/lib/rash.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                           
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/buff-0.0.6/lib/buff.rb:4:in `require'                                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/buff-0.0.6/lib/buff.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                           
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'                                                                                     
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'                                                                 
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'                                                                                        
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'                                                                            
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'                                                                                        
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'                                                                                     
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'                                                                                            
    from /home/action/colocofg_pg/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                     
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'                                                                      
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'                                                              
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'                                                                          
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'                                                                       
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'                                                                 
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'                                                                            
    from /home/action/colocofg_pg/bin/rails:8:in `require'                                                                                                                          
    from /home/action/colocofg_pg/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                 
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'                                                                                     
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'                                                                                     
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'                                                                                            
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                         
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'                                                                                          
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'                                                                              
    from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'                                                              
    from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'                                                              
    from /home/action/colocofg_pg/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                               
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'                                                                                                                                                      
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

The last gems I installed were Buff (github.com/zph/buff) and omniauth-buffer2 (github.com/bufferapp/omniauth-buffer2). And thet it startet trhrowing the messages.

What is causing that mismatch and how to solve it?

Comment: It seems you have declared another class named **Rash** in your application, but you are using a Rash class in library .

Comment: I don't think its the case. The last gems I installed were Buff (https://github.com/zph/buff) and omniauth-buffer2 (https://github.com/bufferapp/omniauth-buffer2). And thet it startet trhrowing the messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this same error after installing these two gems. The problem is that in their documentation, Buffer says to use the "buff" gem when you should be using the "buffer" gem at [github.com/bufferapp/buffer-ruby](http://github.com/bufferapp/buffer-ruby). They forked from [github.com/zph/buff](http://github.com/zph/buff) a few months ago.

Add the following two gems to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'buffer', :github => 'bufferapp/buffer-ruby'
gem 'omniauth-buffer2'
```

And then in your config/(name).rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :buffer, ENV['BUFFER_KEY'], ENV['BUFFER_SECRET']
end
```

And you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall ALL versions of Rash and ALL versions of whatever other gems you installed since you last ran the app (since before the error occurred) and then reinstall the latest versions. You can see all your gems by running "gem list"

There was likely a bug in one or more prior API versions calling the same class.

This happened to me with Rash and the Factual API, and reinstalling only the most recent versions fixed it!